# How do I run without the application opening a browser?

Tags: flash, flash-builder

I'd really prefer my actionscript 3 project to launch in a debugger window outside of a browser, but it always opens into a browser. I browsed through the preferences and help but couldn't find a way to do that.

Is there a way?

Comment: You mean using the Flash Standalone Player?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse FDT, Flash Builder or FlashDevelop?

Comment: @Trevor Boyle, it's tagged Flash Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the [Flash StandAlone Player](http://www.learnwebdesignonline.com/flash-tutorials/running-flash-standalone.htm) may be what you are looking for. You can find instructions to set up the stand alone player to launch while debugging instead of a browser [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=compile_debug_2.html).

Comment: And where in the Flash Builder preferences is this set?  This answer is correct, but is not complete.

Answer (score 2):

Right-Click on your project.
Select "Properties".
Select "ActionScript Compiler".
Uncheck "Generate HTML Wrapper File"

Comment: This controls whether or not the HTML wrapper is created.  It does not control how the swf is launched/debugged.

Comment: @Samuel Disabling the HTML wrapper should launch your application in the standalone player.

Comment: @Trevor Boyle, I always disable the html wrapper for all my projects since we use our own and it always still launches in the browser.

Comment: @Samuel Neff, I am sure you can still get it to run in a browser using your own custom wrapper if you change some further settings, however I doubt @Blub has done this. The purpose of my answer was to give @Blub an easy chance at a goal, so he didn't have to trawl through pages of documentation. If your specific set-up prevents my answer from working, you can see Lee Brimelow do it on this video http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=136 at 2mins 25sec

Comment: @Trevor Boyle, but the point is, just turning off the wrapper does not automatically change the way the app is launched to use the standalone player instead of the browser, which is what @Blub is asking about.

Comment: @Samuel Neff, maybe I am missing the point. What I thought/think @Blub is asking for is to stop the project launching in a browser. If you haven't messed around with other settings, disabling the wrapper will cause it to open in the standalone... like Lee's video shows.

Comment: Hi, I just checked this and @Trevor Boyle is definitely right, it does automatically change the way in which the app is launched. Here is the evidence: http://screenr.com/FG6

Comment: @alidrongo thanks for the effort :) ... I just hope we are all talking about the same thing.